Current flow through a path of zero resistance

In this image, someone told me that there is no current flow through the 6 ohm resistor. Why not? Won't there be any flow till point E as well? If no, does the current choose one path to flow through over another?
FYI, this diagram has been provided in the book.

For your last question see How do electrons know which path to take in a circuit?

This is a poor question. What is your definition of "know" in this context? Until you provide a definition, your question is unclear. Current doesn't "know" anything. You need to reason with proper physics principles instead of informal language. The latter will get you nowhere.

Literally? No current flows anywhere in the "circuit" because there is no source (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source) in the circuit that would make it flow. But if we imagine a source such as a battery connected between A and B, then @jim's answer (below) explains what your friend said.

@Vincent Thacker Sorry for the inconvenience, I just couldn't get my words right. I hope the edited version is better.

IDK if anybody will re-open this question, but in case not: You said, "Won't there be any flow till point E as well? Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL) tells us that if no current flows through the 6 Ohm resistor (as explained in Jim's answer) then no current flows from C to E. More specifically, KCL tells us that the current flowing in to E must equal the current flowing out of E. If the current through the 6 Ohm resistor is 0, then the only way for current in to E and out of E to be equal is if they both are 0.

The 6 $\Omega$ resistor is shorted by the wire and current takes the path of least resistance,  that is through the wire.
Alternatively, the combined resistance of the 6 $\Omega$ resistor and the wire CC (assumed perfect with resistance $0 \; \Omega$) is
$$R_{effective} = \frac{ 0 \; \Omega \times 6 \; \Omega }{ (0 + 6) \; \Omega} = 0 \; \Omega .$$
Referring to the wire as "the $0 \; \Omega$ resistor": Because the $6 \; \Omega$ and $0 \Omega$ resistors are in parallel, the potential difference (pd) across them is the same: this can be calculated as effective resistance $\times$ current. The current through the effective resistance is the current that flows through the $4 \; \Omega$ resistor. Since the effective resistance is zero, the pd across the $6 \; \Omega$ resistor is zero: No current flows through the $6 \; \Omega$ resistor, it all flows through the wire.
This fits with what is happening with the wire: Since the wire has zero resistance, the pd across it is (as well) zero.

Can you explain by taking 'potential difference' as the basis? My teacher did so, he mentioned nothing about least resistance but his answer was convincing (and i forgot what he said)

"current takes the path of least resistance" That is a misleading aphorism. A more informative statement would say, "more of the current flows in the branch with less resistance, but except in this idealized (non-physical) case where one branch has zero resistance, the other branch always gets some of the current."
